# Kubernetes: set environment variables from file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

My Kubernetes deployment has an `initContainer` which fetches a token from a URL. My app container (3rd party) then needs that token as an environment variable.

A possible approach would be: the `initContainer` creates a Kubernetes Secret with the token value; the app container [uses the secret as an environment variable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables) via `env[].valueFrom.secretKeyRef`.

Creating the Secret from the `initContainer` requires [accessing the Kubernetes API from a Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/access-api-from-pod/#directly-accessing-the-rest-api) though, which tends to be a tad cumbersome. For example, [directly accessing the REST API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/access-api-from-pod/#directly-accessing-the-rest-api) requires granting proper permissions to the pod's service account; otherwise, creating the secret will fail with

```
secrets is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:default\" 
cannot create resource \"secrets\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"default\"
```

So I was wondering, isn't there any way to just write the token to a file on an `emptyDir` volume...something like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: fetch-auth-token
          image: curlimages/curl
          command:
            - /bin/sh
          args:
            - -c
            - |
              echo "Fetching token..."
              url=https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MaxHorstmann/a99823d5aff66fe2ad4e7a4e2a2ee96b/raw/662c19aa96695e52384337bdbd761056bb324e72/token
              curl $url > /auth-token/token
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /auth-token
              name: auth-token
...
      volumes:
        - name: auth-token
          emptyDir: {}
```

... and then somehow use that file to populate an environment variable in the app container, similar to `env[].valueFrom.secretKeyRef`, along the lines of:

```
      containers:
        - name: my-actual-app
          image: thirdpartyappimage
          env:
            - name: token
              valueFrom:
                fileRef:
                  path: /auth-token/token
            # ^^^^ this does not exist
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /auth-token
              name: auth-token
```

Unfortunately, there's no `env[].valueFrom.fileRef`.

I considered overwriting the app container's `command` with a shell script which loads the environment variable from the file before launching the main command; however, the container image doesn't even contain a shell.

Is there any way to set the environment variable in the app container from a file?

Comment: Consider creating a K8s Operator that makes the request and yields the relevant env variables.

Comment: That's probably more work than dealing with the service account permissions. :) Appreciate the suggestion though!

Comment: In fact, you would need to deal with exactly the same service account permissions, because the operator would *also* need to be able to create Secrets or ConfigMaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Creating the Secret from the initContainer requires accessing the Kubernetes API from a Pod though, which tends to be a tad cumbersome...

It's not actually all that bad; you only need to add a ServiceAccount, Role, and RoleBinding to your deployment manifests.

The ServiceAccount manifest is minimal, and you only need it if you don't want to grant permissions to the `default` service account in your namespace:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: secretmaker
```

Then your Role grants access to secrets (we need `create` and `delete` permissions, and having `get` and `list` is handy for debugging):

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  labels:
    app: env-example
  name: secretmaker
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - create
  - get
  - delete
  - list
```

A RoleBinding connects the ServiceAccount to the Role:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    app: env-example
  name: secretmaker
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: secretmaker
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: secretmaker
  namespace: default
```

And with those permissions in place, the Deployment is relatively simple:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: env-example
  name: env-example
  namespace: env-example
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: env-example
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: env-example
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: secretmaker
      initContainers:
      - command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - |
          echo "Fetching token..."
          url=https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MaxHorstmann/a99823d5aff66fe2ad4e7a4e2a2ee96b/raw/662c19aa96695e52384337bdbd761056bb324e72/token
          curl $url -o /tmp/authtoken
          kubectl delete secret authtoken > /dev/null 2>&1
          kubectl create secret generic authtoken --from-file=AUTH_TOKEN=/tmp/authtoken
        image: docker.io/alpine/k8s:1.25.6
        name: create-auth-token
      containers:
      - name: my-actual-app
        image: docker.io/alpine/k8s:1.25.6
        command:
        - sleep
        - inf
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: authtoken
```

The application container here is a no-op that runs `sleep inf`; that gives you the opportunity to inspect the environment by running:

```
kubectl exec -it deployment/env-example -- env
```

Look for the `AUTH_TOKEN` variable created by our `initContainer`.

---

All the manifests mentioned here can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-75265056-createsecret).

Comment: Thanks! Like I stated in my question, the image unfortunately does not contain a shell. :)

Comment: I missed that; sorry! I've udpated the answer to hopefully be a bit more useful.